# Can't install libxml2 for python with whl file

Tags: python, libxml2

I am having a very hard time installing libxml2. I am trying to use a wheel file to install it with the command line. I have Python 3.8 but I don't see any .whl files for Python 3.8. Do I need to use an earlier version of Python?

Here is the error when I attempt to install with the whl file in my Python folder:

```
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>pip install libxml2_python-2.9.3-cp27-none-win32.whl
ERROR: libxml2_python-2.9.3-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Wheel is installed:

```
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>python -m pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\jack\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.33.6)
```

And here is some more info:

```
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>where python
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\python.exe

C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>where pip
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>where pip3
C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.exe

C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32>python -c"import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize('P'))"
32
```

Comment: every Python version may have own version of module - and `cp27` means it is module only for `Python 2.7`. Using `pip3 search lxml2` I see `libxml2-python3` which should be for Python 3 but it may be only for 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. Python 3.8 is very new and better use 3.7 and wait few months before 3.8 will be better tested

Answer (score 0):

The .whl file is valid for python 2 not 3.